# How can a call to suprocess.checkoutput() return nothing when I just echo a string

Tags: python, subprocess

In python, I try to run some command but I can't get it work, to sum up here is a script that should execute four simple commands via subproscess, store theirs respective outputs and then display them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

output_1 = None
output_2 = None
output_3 = None
output_4 = None

print "Start"
try:
    output_1 = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-al"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output_2 = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "'Hi'"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output_3 = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "\"Hi\""], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output_4 = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hi"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    print "Command '%s' return exit code %s:\n\n%s" % (ex.cmd, ex.returncode, ex.output)

print "Out 1: '%s'" % output_1
print "Out 2: '%s'" % output_2
print "Out 3: '%s'" % output_3
print "Out 4: '%s'" % output_4
```

I do not undestand why there is no 'Hi' in my outputs... Here is the output I get:

```
Start
Out 1: '
test
undefined10_error.png
undefined20_error.png
undefined35_error.png
undefined40_error.png
'
Out 2: '
'
Out 3: '
'
Out 4: '
'
```

Comment: You specified `shell=True` but passed a list of args.

Comment: @Blurp Thanks. It works. But could you provide some more info what are the difference between `shell=True` and `shell=False`. Even form [the actual doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) I do not understand well why my example didn't worked.

Comment: Plus, what if I want to give this echo a variable that I know is defined ?

Answer (score 1):

By passing the `shell=True` argument, [you are telling the interpreter to execute the command as a single string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). This means that the first argument needs to be a string. If you look at the output of your first command you'll notice that you're not getting the flags `am`, but just a standard `ls`.

If you want to use `shell=True`, pass the argument as a str:

```
> subprocess.check_output("echo 'Hello World!'", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b'Hello World!\n'
```

If you're planning on using variables, you'll need to escape them yourself with [shelex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

To use a local variable:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> local_variable = 'Hi \'world"'
>>> command = 'echo {}'.format(shlex.quote(local_variable))
>>> subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b'Hi \'world"\n'
```

Comment: What about a variable defined in the command line ? Like doing `echo  "$MY_VAR"` but from python.
`subprocess.check_output("echo \"$BASE_URL\"", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` return nothing

Comment: I've a variable called `SKUNK_IP`. I just tried this: `>>> subprocess.check_output('echo $SKUNK_IP', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` I received: 
`b'127.0.0.1\n'`. This makes me think your `BASE_URL` is not an environment variable

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thx a lot for your help